# How do I make my links in Wordpress not add itself to the existing URL?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I'm guessing there is a simple solution to this, but I can't seem to get my phrasing right when searching for it, so I'll post it here.

I have some links that look like this in Wordpress:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'hjemmeside', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'hjemmeside', true); ?></a>
```

Just regular links that I echo in my single template to create user homepage/facebook etc. The problem is when you click it, the link will just adds itself to the end of the URL:

Example:

wordpress.com/single

when clicking the link:

wordpress.com/single/www.homepagelink.com

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: My guess is that wordpress isn't adding anything. If you have the URL without preceding `http://` in the field it is shown that way by the browser. Check the generated source code in your browser.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, with a little more elaboration. If you want you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that wordpress isn't adding anything. If you have the URL without preceding `http://` in the custom field it is shown that way by the browser. If you check the generated source code with your browser you will find the code like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.homepagelink.com">www.homepagelink.com</a>
```

Without `http://` or other valid URL schema this is interpreted by the browser as a relative link and handled as such.

You can either add the `http://` in the field value or you place a wrapper function in the `functions.php` of your theme to make sure it is always interpreted as URL regardless what was put in the field.

```
function my_field_link($id, $field) {
  $value = get_post_meta($id, $field, true);
  if (substr($value, 0, 7) == "http://") return $value;
  return "http://" . $value;
}
```

Then you can call this function like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo my_field_link($post->ID, prefix.'hjemmeside'); ?>"><?php echo my_field_link($post->ID, prefix.'hjemmeside'); ?></a>
```

Now the link will always start with `http://`.

Note: If you expect to have other URL schemas in use (https, ftp, scp, etc.) you should adapt the function accordingly.